# How do I clean up this code to make a list of buttons in JavaScript that will display specific information, while getting rid of other content?

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I am new to every part of this, so let me start by apologizing if I'm not concise enough or use wrong terminology. I have successfully created several methods that work to allow users to click various buttons on a page, when a specific button is clicked appropriate content is displayed. MY question is- what could I do to clean it up a bit? I've thought about attempting to create an array for the buttons themselves, an array for the content and a function using if/else statements to display the appropriate content for the various button clicks. If it weren't for having other content disappear, I feel I might be onto something. Alas, like I said, I'm new to this and any thoughts about logic, methods, classes, etc. that could help me shave lines off would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is how I got things to work thus far. If you need to see the HTML that this works with, I'm more than happy to post.

```
function chapter1Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", chapter1Display, false);

function chapter2Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("2").addEventListener("click", chapter2Display, false);

function chapter3Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click", chapter3Display, false);

function chapter4Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click", chapter4Display, false);

function chapter5Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("5").addEventListener("click", chapter5Display, false);

function chapter6Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("6").addEventListener("click", chapter6Display, false);

function chapter7Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("7").addEventListener("click", chapter7Display, false);

function chapter8Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("8").addEventListener("click", chapter8Display, false);

function chapter9Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("9").addEventListener("click", chapter9Display, false);

function chapter10Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("10").addEventListener("click", chapter10Display, false);

function chapter11Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("11").addEventListener("click", chapter11Display, false);

function chapter12Display() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementById("12").addEventListener("click", chapter12Display, false);

function refresh() {
  document.getElementById("filler").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("ch1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch5").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch6").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch7").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch8").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch9").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch10").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch11").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("ch12").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("refresher").addEventListener("click", refresh, false);
```

Comment: Use the HTML `class` attribute, which is best accessed through `Element.classList`. So, alread have `.hid{ display:none; }` in your CSS then set and remove you `class`es with `Element.classList.add('hid')`, `Element.classList.remove('hid')` and `Element.classList.toggle('hid')`.

Comment: it would be easier to understand with a bit of html, no need to motivate your 12 chapters to explain, 2 or 3 would be enough, and luckily you don't need miles, this reading would have been even more boring

Comment: What about a good old radio button group? That would need no JS at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class of `chapter` to all those elements with id `ch[x]`.
Then you can have the following function:

```
const showChapter = number => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.chapter').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(`ch${number}`).style.display = "block";
}
```

It hides all chapters, then displays only the one you ask for.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is the kind of thing you are looking for?

```js
const navButtons  = document.getElementById('nav-buttons')
  ,   sectionList = document.querySelectorAll('section')
  ;
navButtons.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('button')) return
  showSection(e.target.value)
  }
function showSection(sectionId)
  {
  sectionList.forEach(sct=>
    {
    sct.style.display= (sct.id===sectionId) ? 'block':'none'
    })
  }
showSection('filler')
```

```html
<nav id="nav-buttons">
  <button value="filler">Table of contents</button>
  <button value="ch1">chapter 1</button>
  <button value="ch2">chapter 2</button>
  <button value="ch3">chapter 3</button>
</nav>
<section id="filler">
  <h4>filler</h4>
  filler text
</section>
<section id="ch1">
  <h4>ch1</h4>
  ch1 text
</section>
<section id="ch2">
  <h4>ch2</h4>
  ch2 text
</section>
<section id="ch3">
  <h4>ch3</h4>
  ch3 text
</section>
```